# ArcGIS Server REST API: at which URL can I acquire a token?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

I'm working with the ArcGIS Server REST API in a python script. In order to access my server, I need to generate a token and put it into the `https://myserverurl.com/arcgis/rest/login` page, however, I'm unable to find the URL where a token is generated. This page says `"To acquire this token, go to https://myserverurl.com/arcgis and enter https://myserverurl.com/arcgis/rest' for the 'Webapp URL' parameter."` This link redirects me to `https://myserverurl.com/arcgis/sharing/rest/generatetoken`, but it is an empty page.

Some URLs I've tried include: `https://myserverurl.com/arcgis/rest/generatetoken` and `https://myserverurl.com/arcgis/rest/authentication`, among others. ESRI's documentation asks for `http://gisserver.domain.com:6080/arcgis/tokens`, but this is not working either.

Am I missing something?

Comment: two things: make sure get requests are enabled http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/linux/enable-token-acquisition-through-an-http-get-request.htm and then you will have to include the username and password in the url like this: http://domain.net:6080/arcgis/tokens/generateToken?username=theusername&password=thepassword&client=requestip

Comment: mark my mine as the answer so that the question will be marked as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two things: make sure get requests are enabled server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/linux/… and then you will have to include the username and password in the url like this: http://domain.net:6080/arcgis/tokens/generateToken?username=theusername&password=thepassword&client=requestip

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have your answer to enable GET requests, but I just wanted to mention to get the url you can always make a request to the `info` resource to obtain the `tokenServicesUrl`.  For example, if your domain is `gis.your-domain.com`, you can make a call like this:

`http://<your-domain>/arcgis/<instance>/info?f=pjson`

This will return JSON similar to this:

```
{
 "currentVersion": 10.31,
 "fullVersion": "10.3.1",
 "soapUrl": "http://gis.your-domain.com/arcgis/services",
 "secureSoapUrl": "https://gis.your-domain.com/arcgis/services",
 "authInfo": {
  "isTokenBasedSecurity": true,
  "tokenServicesUrl": "https://gis.your-domain.com/arcgis/tokens/",
  "shortLivedTokenValidity": 480
 }
}
```

Then to actually obtain the token, hit the `tokenServicesUrl` with your credentials.